# Import CSV while populating variables referenced in the file

Tags: csv, powershell, import

I have a CSV file that contains lines like this:

```
"Title","Path"
"News","/somepath/news.json/$variable1$variable2"
"Boards","/somepath/$year/$variable3/boardfile.json"
```

I set all these variables in the script and then import data using `Import-Csv` cmdlet. As a result, I get object with Title and Path properties and that's what I need. But the problem is that the variables in the CSV file are not getting replaced with actual values during import.
I know there is a solution with `Get-Content` and `ExpandVariable`, but it produces an array of strings, and I would rather have an object (or maybe a hashtable?) with properties similar to what `Import-Csv` produces.
Is there a way to replace variables with values while still using `Import-Csv` and get a full-featured object as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Import-Csv` doesn't expand variables in imported data, so the values in your CSV behave as if they were in single quoted strings. You need something like this to get the variables expanded after import:

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\your.csv' | Select-Object Title,
    @{n='Path';e={$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_.Path)}}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what's being done in this part?
@{n='Name';e={$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_.Path)}}

Comment: That's a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx).

Comment: Why can't we just use ForEach-Object, perform ExpandString($_.Path) on each record and assign new values back?

Comment: I didn't say you can't. The above is just one (and IMO in this case more convenient) way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Calculated property really solves my task. Thank you!